# How to improve monitor saturation?

Tags: colors

Recently I have installed Ubuntu on my laptop and noticed that colors are very dull and washed out and the color calibration option is grayed out.

```
-GPU: Intel UHD 620
-Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
-monitor: built in laptop display
```

Comment: *colors are very dull and washed out* Compared to what, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Use VibrantLinux - great simple software to boost color saturation
https://flathub.org/apps/details/io.github.libvibrant.vibrantLinux